# Do airliners have integrated ladders that lead right into the cockpit?

Tags: airliner, airbus

I was watching *World War Z* and when they were bailing out of Israel, a bunch of armed troops held up a Belarus Ariways Airbus A310 right on the runway.  The pilots dropped a ladder out from near the front of the plane and our heroes climbed up out of danger and directly into the cockpit.  Is this a real thing or just Plot Device™?

Comment: Cockpits will have emergency egress methods like ropes or ladders that once deployed can be used for ingress.

Comment: @casey often this means punching out a hatch or window plate that would make going for a flight afterwards challenging. Not sure about the A310.

Comment: @dvnrrs depends on the plane. Many airplanes have windows that can open and close (e.g. emb-145, b737) or hatches that can be closed again.